# Methods in class problem (can't update all objects, only one affected)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

In this code i want to make paralax effect with some elements, but whatever i do only one of elements is moving, i dont know where's problem :/

I tried diffrent things but only the last form array (ParaElements) is moving no matter how many obj were made.

```js
function ParaElement(x, y, z, id) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
  this.id = id;

  document.getElementById("paralax").innerHTML +=
    '<div class="para-elmt"> </div>';

  this.htmlObj = document.getElementsByClassName("para-elmt")[id];

  this.positionChange = function (tx, ty) {
    this.htmlObj.style.top = String(tx) + "px";
    this.htmlObj.style.left = String(ty) + "px";
    this.htmlObj.style.zIndex = this.z;
  };

  this.positionChange(this.x, this.y);

  this.scrollHandler = function () {
    let scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let tx = this.x - scrollPosition / this.z;
    let ty = this.y;
    this.positionChange(tx, ty);
  };
}

var ParaElements = [];
ParaElements.push(new ParaElement("30", "100", "25", "0"));
ParaElements.push(new ParaElement("100", "300", "50", "1"));
ParaElements.push(new ParaElement("200", "200", "10", "2"));

$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < ParaElements.length; i++) {
    ParaElements[i].scrollHandler();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
#paralax {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}
#paralax .para-elmt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: teal;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
      <div id="paralax">

      </div>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using innerHTML each time you initiate a ParaElement, you are breaking the previous selectors you used to grab your elements. That's why only the last one is moving. Something like this should do the trick.

```
function ParaElement(x, y, z, id) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
  this.id = id;

  this.htmlObj = document.getElementsByClassName("para-elmt")[this.id];

  this.positionChange = function (tx, ty) {
    this.htmlObj.style.top = String(tx) + "px";
    this.htmlObj.style.left = String(ty) + "px";
    this.htmlObj.style.zIndex = this.z;
  };

  this.positionChange(this.x, this.y);

  this.scrollHandler = function () {
    let scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    let tx = this.x - scrollPosition / this.z;
    let ty = this.y;
    this.positionChange(tx, ty);
  };
}

// Let's define the number of element we want, by creating an array with the differents parameters.
// I removed the last parameter from the arrays because it can be added directly when we will loop over the arrays.
let paraElementsParams = [["30", "100", "25"], ["100", "300", "50"], ["200", "200", "10"]]

var ParaElements = [];
// Instead of initializing by hand, let's loop over the elements in our parameters array so we can first create all the dom elements
for (let i = 0; i < paraElementsParams.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("paralax").innerHTML += '<div class="para-elmt"> </div>';
}
// Then, let's loop again so we can initialize our elements without losing the node references.
for (let i = 0; i < paraElementsParams.length; i++) {
  // we add i at the end of the initialization using the current loop index
  ParaElements.push(new ParaElement(...paraElementsParams[i], i));
}

$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < ParaElements.length; i++) {
    ParaElements[i].scrollHandler(); 
  }
});
```